# How do I use Azure Media Services in Xamarin iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, azure, xamarin, azure-media-services

The Azure Media Service has a [SDK and advertising integration with iOS.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/introduction-to-the-media-player-framework-for-ios/)

Is there any simple way to import this into Xamarin Forms, or Xamarin.iOS / Android?

Comment: Im not sure but I think that you can use also native ios and android video players for playing videos from Azure Media Services. http://www.slideshare.net/GuadalupeCasuso/consuming-media-services-clients

Answer (score 0):

Azure Media Services has a Rest API. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh973617.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Media Player Framework for iOS has been removed from the document and on WindowsAzure Github while it was public before.

You could try HTML5 [Azure Web Media Player](http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/), might spend lot of efforts but this could be possible solution for both iOS and Android (so Xamarin.Forms is valid too) since it will be embedded in a WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with nuget packages? Windows Azure Media Services .NET SDK is a good option for Xamarin that is available via nuget. There's a nice tutorial here at [Microsoft's Azure website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dotnet-get-started).

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to communicate with AMS directly from your phone APP? Is there not a mid-tier that could handle the communications back to AMS instead? Or is your goal to have users enter their Media Services credentials in the APP somehow? Or are you planning to put your own Media Services creds in the app code?